# Is it possible to automate the process of installing application from a dmg file?

Tags: automation, applescript

The process can be described as,

1. open dmg file
2. find the .app file in the mounted dmg disk and copy it to Applications folder.
3. Unmount the dmg disk
4. Move the .dmg file to Trash

Comment: yes - it is possible.

Comment: show your approach

Comment: Not really.  Thanks to Apple’s quarantine procedures that were implemented in High Sierra, moving an application that has been downloaded **must** be done manually.  If not, you get all sorts of annoying permission restrictions, which can impair functionality of the application (this is all based on security ideology).  The rest of those steps you can automate easily and without a problem (in fact, I already do).  Just a pain about this new restriction.

Comment: Couldn't you bypass these restrictions with non-apple tools that can read dmg files, e.g. 7zip?