# Is there a way to unarchive a dmg file like a tar.gz file? (Using Mac OS)

Tags: bash, macos, binaryfiles

I'm trying to use a program that uses Linux versions of other programs.
I ran this in bash:

```
c3dpath=$( command -v c3d )
if [[ -z "${c3dpath}" ]]; then
    echo "Command c3d was not found. Downloading and installing software to ${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d. Path will be added to PATH environment variable."
    mkdir -p "${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d/"
    wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/c3d/c3d/Nightly/c3d-nightly-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzvf c3d-nightly-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz && mv c3d-1.1.0-Linux-x86_64/* "${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d/" && \
    rm c3d-nightly-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
    export PATH="${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d/c3d-1.1.0-Linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH"
fi
```

But it downloads the linux version of the program files into my directory -- yielding the error:

```
{..omitted}/HippMapp3r/depends/c3d/bin/c3d: cannot execute binary file
Return Code: 126
```

I understand in order for this to work on my computer, I need to use the version for Mac OS, however, I stuck on how one might go about "unarchiving" the files contained within a .dmg file so I can access c3d in bin.

I edited it to this, but I understand I cannot use the tar -xzvf command in this context -- is there an equivalent to tar -xzvf to "unpack" dmg files?

```
c3dpath=$( command -v c3d )
if [[ -z "${c3dpath}" ]]; then
    echo "Command c3d was not found. Downloading and installing software to ${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d. Path will be added to PATH environment variable."
    mkdir -p "${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d/"
    wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/c3d/c3d/Nightly/c3d-nightly-MacOS-x86_64.dmg && \
    tar -xzvf c3d-nightly-MacOS-x86_64.dmg * "${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d/" && \
    rm c3d-nightly-MacOS-x86_64.dmg
    export PATH="${SCRIPTPATH}/depends/c3d/c3d-nightly-MacOS-x86_64/bin/:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: You mount the DMG as a disk volume, and then just copy from the directory you mounted it on to.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706973/is-it-possible-to-automate-the-process-of-installing-application-from-a-dmg-file

Answer (score 1):

Try using 7-zip. You can install it on a Mac with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install p7zip
```

Then run it with:

```
7z
```

Please see comment by @StefanSchmidt about a possible alternative package.

Comment: There are actually two Homebrew packages that provide 7-Zip: [`p7zip`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/p7zip) and [`sevenzip`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sevenzip). `p7zip` is a fork and `sevenzip` the original implementation. It might be of interest, that `p7zip` does not  currently support APFS images, the `sevenzip` formula however does.

Comment: @StefanSchmidt Cool - thank you for the tip. I'll add a note into my answer so it's more visible.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to mount the DMG file.
command: hdiutil mount test.dmg